# Stack Exchange sites should set an HTTP cache expiry on their favicon.ico logos

Tags: feature-request, favicon, http

Occasionally I'd receive mysterious `HTTP/1.1 429 Too many requests` responses from Stack Exchange, despite having made relatively few requests.

I've now discovered the cause.

I have a web page containing nothing but links.
One section is dedicated to Stack Exchange sites:

[image: Names of many SE sites, each with two logos]

Notice that each site displays the logo for the site and for the meta-site.
That's a lot of favicon.ico files.

Apparently, every time I load or refresh this page of links, rather than using the web browser's cache, every one of those logos generates another fetch request from the site.
When I'm making updates to the page I might refresh it several times, hence the 429 response.

I can understand why most individual question pages shouldn't be cached (they are updated so frequently), but that isn't true of the `favicon.ico` files, which aren't likely to change without a lot of advance warning.

I know that mine is a very minor problem, and happens only in very unusual circumstances (or does everyone's page loads generate an extra fetch?), but if anyone ever has the opportunity to add an HTTP Expiry for each site's logos, it would be appreciated.

Comment: You should... not ever do this. Consider downloading all the icons and keeping them on your own servers. It may resolve *your* issue, but every single user who hits that page is going to download however many icons and also hit that problem if they don't already have them all downloaded. Never hotlink that many things from another site at once.

Comment: @animuson, good advice in general, but this is my personal page of handy links. It's hard to imagine "every single user" as anyone but myself.

Comment: That is still a very bad idea, and all the more reason to just download the icons you need locally. Favicons are by default stored in separate heavy caches in browsers because they rarely change. They're not really meant to be hotlinked in that fashion and it is uncommon to place cache times on them because it is not usually needed. E.g. Facebook has no cache period whatsoever (and explicitly sends no-cache values) on its favicon. Google uses the same default that we do.

Comment: So far as I can tell, they *are* setting `max-age` with the `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: @animuson I suggest a [tag:status-declined] here and an answer with your reasoning. It makes sense.

Comment: @Kevin, `lynx -dump -head https://meta.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico | grep cache-control` produces "cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate".

Comment: @RayButterworth: Follow the redirect.

Comment: If you really want to hotlink favicons, doing it from our CDN instead of directly may work out better for you: e.g. `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchangemeta/Img/favicon.ico`

Comment: @AdamLear, thanks, but for this page it is done by generic JS that simply finds every link's URL and inserts code for that site's icon in front of it. Automatic, robust, and no-maintenance.